# Audio Playlists - Multiple file type support?

Tags: embed, audio

I know when uploading an audio file (mp3) to a WordPress post, I can embed the player. I can then edit the embed to also include a link to the ogg version of the file to support Firefox. I can't seem to find any documentation for doing the same thing with an audio playlist. When creating the playlist, using the WordPress media playlist creator, what ends up being created is a shortcake with audio file IDs. Can I have a playlist that has both the mp3 and the ogg accounted for?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not supported currently in the core playlist as I understand it.

*The following are just some rough ideas:*

Within the `WPPlaylistView.playCurrentSrc()` method, in the `wp-playlist.js` file, we have:

```
this.mejs.setSrc( this.playerNode.attr( 'src' ) );
```

This is currently only for a single source.

I checked the definition of `srcSet()` in *MediaElment.js* and [found](https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/blob/03d04feae22f4bb1729475c788c61cb44e3cb177/build/mediaelement.js#L593):

```
// This can be a url string
// or an array [{src:'file.mp4',type:'video/mp4'},{src:'file.webm',type:'video/webm'}]
setSrc: function (url) {
```

So it looks like there is a multiple file-type support in the *MediaElment.js*  library.

**Test ideas**

If we had e.g. `mp3` and `ogg` attributes, then the array might look like:

```
this.mejs.setSrc(
    [
        { src:this.playerNode.attr( 'mp3' ), type:'audio/mp3'},
        { src:this.playerNode.attr( 'ogg' ), type:'audio/ogg'}            
    ]
);
```

To test this we could have an `ogg` version for each `mp3` media file in the playlist. Then we could add this array element:

```
src:this.playerNode.attr( 'src' ).replace( '.mp3', '.ogg' ), type:'audio/ogg'}
```

into the source array.

I'm not sure if one can override only the `WPPlaylistView.playCurrentSrc()` method or extend the `WPPlaylistView` Backbone view.

For testing one could e.g. dequeue the core `wp-playlist.js` file and enqueue a modified version instead.

Another approach might be to look for a way to adjust the player through the `MediaElementPlayer` object or with some other javascript workarounds.

*Hope you can investigate this further ;-)*